# Updating my monero master

Tags: github, build, source

So I cloned the monero github onto my computer around 2 months ago.

How do I update the entire thing to the most current release? Is there a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, assuming you have not made any branches, and that doesn't sound likely, follow these steps:

- if you have made any changes to the repo: git stash
- git pull --rebase
- if you have made any changes to the repo: git stash pop

So in the likely case you haven't changed anything, it's just one step. Then build again (make).

If you *did* make changes, there's a possibility your changes will conflict with the upstream changes. In that case, it gets complicated, and you'll want to read the git docs. If the changes you made were trivial, it's easier to redo them manually.