# How to send funds with a watch-only and cold wallet set up?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, watch-only-wallet

So I have a cold wallet set up with an online watching only. My question is how do i go about sending funds with this set up? As well as updating the cold wallet balance if that's necessary. This is not a paper wallet and I'm using QubesOS.I tried creating a transaction normally following this [guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing) but it wouldn't create the `unsigned_monero_tx` file and instead displays `Error: this is a watch only wallet`.

Answer (score 2):

[This SE post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/offline-transaction-signing-what-are-the-details) asks questions about cold transaction signing that may or may not lead you to your answer.  That post links to another SE post, which describes the process of cold transaction signing.

It appears you may already know much/all of the information from those two posts, so maybe you're just using not the most recent version of monerod.  Did you download prebuilt binaries, or did you build yourself?  If you didn't build yourself, you may need to.  If you did build yourself, you may need to update, which can be found in [this SE post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/updating-my-monero-master).